# Ubuntu 14.04 installation of the dropbox daemon failed

Tags: dropbox

I know questions like this were asked several times before, but non of those solutions helped me out.
I tried to install dropbox on a clean Ubuntu 14.04 installation, but I can't get it to work.

First I tried to install the nautilus-dropbox package from the default source, then I tried to install the dropbox package from the dropbox third party source. Both installations failed to install the dropbox daemon, even installing it manually failed.

The download of the daemon completes fine every time, but the installation process fails at 60% saying my Internet connection failed.

Screenshot : [Dropbox installation failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QMwp.png)

There is no proxy in my local network and there is no proxy configured in the Ubuntu settings.

I hope somebody knows a solution for this problem.

Thanks

Panzki

Comment: Not really the right place to ask this. Maybe Ubuntu forums or dropbox support. This question won't help others. Side note, could your internet provider or network provider be blocking dropbox?